# SeLion Framework in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My manager is asking me to work with [SeLion](https://github.com/paypal/SeLion) framework. Which is developed top of selenium.

If anyone here worked on selion, please share your feedback and documents to learn SeLion

Comment: Could you please edit your question to be more specific? "Any help is appreciated" type questions typically get closed as too broad.